# Net Core MVC change URL routing parameter to be a # fragment

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I want my final route parameter to turn into a URL fragment once the page has loaded.

So if I submit a URL like:

```
https://mysite/controller/param1/param2
```

And it hits my controller method via the route I've set up

```
public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2)
```

How can I somehow re-route this so that the resulting loaded page shows as

```
https://mysite/controller/param1#param2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the `RedirectToAction()` overloads that takes the fragment paramter to generate the URL with the fragment:

> public virtual RedirectToActionResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, string fragment);

But first, you would need to setup a route to map a request like `https://mysite/controller/param1/param2` to something that can take those parameters off the URL and call `RedirectToAction()` overload. I created a separate controller called `FragmentController` and declared a method called `Process()` there:

```cs
// Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "fragment",
            pattern: "fragment/{controllerName}/{actionName}/{fragmentName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "fragment", action = "process" });

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(...);
    });
}
```

See that new route mapping is looking for any request that starts with `/fragment`, followed by 3 parameters, and those parameters would get properly mapped to the `Process()` action in `FragmentController`:

```cs
// FragmentController.cs
public class FragmentController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Process(string controllerName, string actionName, 
        string fragmentName)
    {
        // You can do anything you want with those parameters, i.e., validations
        return RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, fragmentName);
    }
}
```

That's it. So if a request like `https://localhost:44370/fragment/home/privacy/heading1` comes in

[image]

It would be properly mapped to the fragment controller process action:

[image]

After calling the `RedirectToAction()` overload, it will correctly redirect to the controller and the action you want, with the fragment:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @David Liang What would the Action that I'm redirecting to look like and how would it set the fragment in the URL?

Comment: The action it's redirecting to just the privacy action method in the home controller. It's the template that came with VS2019 when you build a new MVC project. For "how would it set the fragment in the URL" - I have shared that part already in my answer - just by passing the fragment into one of the overloads of `RedirectToAction()`.